# Jquery not applying on dynamic elements created in context menu

Tags: dynamic, contextmenu, jquery-on

I have a script containing `$('a').on('click', function () {alert($(this).attr('class')); });`
In my contextmenu function, I create a list with links

```
$(function () {
$('a').on('contextmenu', function (event) {
        $("<ul id='menu'></ul>")
        .append('<li><a href="#" class="test">Test 1</a></li>')
        .append('<li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>')
        .appendTo("body")
        .css({ top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px" });
        return false;
    });
```

});

However, the first piece of code (the on click event) does not fire when the link in the list is clicked. However, it fires for every other link on the page. How can I fix this so that my script works on dynamic elements

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207393/742624

Comment: Yes, I am using the "on" function and not "live"

Comment: right, but notice answer calls `on` on a *containing* element of the dynamic element you want as 'this' in your callback. So something like this should work: `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){...});`.

Comment: Tried that too but does not work...

Comment: Seems to work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnoble01/3ajfc/1/)

Comment: oh my bad. I change binding on the contextmenu instead on that of the link. THANK you that works. I Will accept any answer you post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a rehash of another [SO question](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Calling the jQuery [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on $(document) and providing the 'selector' option will bind the callback to dynamically added elements matching the selector parameter.

That is, this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
  alert( $(this).attr('class') ); 
});
```

instead of this:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
  alert($(this).attr('class')); 
});
```